# set Default projection in postgis table

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, sql, srid

I've set the SRID 4326 for a table having geometry column, but when i insert a geometry without SRID, i get an error because no SRID specified is interpreted as -1 or 0, so how i can set a default SRID to insert geometries without specifying SRID each time.

Comment: I don't think you can directly, as it is possible, but not advisable to mix geometries with different SRIDs in same column. You could possibly do it via a trigger, though personally I have never found wrapping geometries in ST_SETSRID to be very arduous.

Comment: i'm not looking to mix geometries with different SRID, in my case i'm using hibernate spatial, i find it little bad to set SRID for each geometry creation.

Comment: That is fair enough, I know you hibernate guys are purists :D. I have used GeoDjango a bit, and it seems to be quite normal there to have to explicitly set the SRID in your models. A before insert trigger is what you are looking for, I think.

Comment: anybody know an answer for this? I've got the same case - I don't want to mix SRIDs, but some software tries to insert geometries that don't specify an SRID. I want those inserts to succeed (in other words it is safe to assume the geometries are in the SRID of the table)

Comment: i think a insert trigger would do the task

Comment: I guess there's no connection-level variable or anything to specify the SRID of geometries without them then?